# how can I fix blender not responding after I activate default hair particles system? BLENDER JUST STOPS RESPONDING -Lenovo CORE i5 8GB RAM-

Tags: particles

When I try to use Blender default hair particle system it just stops responding even though it has not used my entire RAM and CPU. Is there a way to fix this?
On -Lenovo IdeaPad S145 CORE i5 8GB RAM-

Comment: How long did you wait for a reaction? Does blender take up any cpu percentage during the "freeze"?

Comment: the CPU usage remains relatively low, it never goes over 20%

Comment: That's because in this case, blender uses only a single thread and not all of your CPU cores. What exactly are you trying? How many particles and children do you have? When exactly does your system seem to freeze up?

Comment: Emission (1000, 0 seed,) Children Interpolated ( Display amount 10, render amount 100) even with its default settings it still does freeze. what intrigues me is that it doesn't freeze immediately after creating the hair particles, it times it takes few minutes. at times can even groom the hair to the shape I want before it freezes. it does this with everything, when ever I try to create character hair or fur

Comment: Did you try different blender versions?
What display mode and render engine do you use?

Comment: I first noticed this when I was using 2.82, I thought maybe the blender version was the problem, upgraded to 2.91 still the same results. it does this in Solid View Cycles, I haven't tried Material or Rendered views since solid is less demanding compared to the two.

Comment: Hm... Then I am runnning out of ideas. While your PC is certainly not a beast of a machine, it should be able to handle that kind of work. I assume, your drivers are up to date and your machine is in good condition (no blocked air ducts or fans)?

Comment: I really really appreciate the help thanks a bunch. where you are right at this moment I am there. I tried everything my PC is up to date. but it is a small dent i'll work around the problem. Thanks again.